# Xarray: Clean way to deal with dimensionless arrays returned by indexing one element

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, python-xarray

## Description

I need to take out a single value from an xarray.DataArray. What I get is an array -- without dimensions -- containing the value. How do I get the value directly?

The returned array **can't be indexed**, however most numpy methods can work with it. In some cases however, I need the value not as an array but as it'd type itself.

## Example

I'd like to do something like the following:

```
In [1]: import xarray as xr       

In [2]: d = xr.DataArray([list('abc'), list('def')], 
   ...:                  coords=[[1, 2], list('abc')])

In [3]: d.sel(dict(dim_0=1, dim_1='a')).upper()  # What I'd like to do.                   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-6d58c154742f> in <module>
----> 1 d.sel(dict(dim_0=1, dim_1='a')).upper()

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/core/common.py in __getattr__(self, name)
    181                     return source[name]
    182         raise AttributeError("%r object has no attribute %r" %
--> 183                              (type(self).__name__, name))
    184 
    185     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value: Any) -> None:

AttributeError: 'DataArray' object has no attribute 'upper'
```

This doesn't work either:

```
In [4]: d.sel(dict(dim_0=1, dim_1='a')).values.upper()              
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-85757efcdeeb> in <module>
----> 1 d.sel(dict(dim_0=1, dim_1='a')).values.upper()

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'upper'
```

What does work, but I need positional indexing for this:

```
In [5]: d.values[0, 0].upper()    
Out[5]: 'A'
```

And also (somewhat verbose):

```
In [6]: d.sel(dict(dim_0=1, dim_1='a')).values.flatten()[0].upper()
Out[6]: 'A'
```

## Expected result

Shouldn't xarray in this case return the plain value, just like numpy does?

Or an array with only one value, but **all the dimensions**,
which the can be positionally indexed:

```
In [7]: d.sel(dict(dim_0=1, dim_1='a'))
Out[7]:
<xarray.DataArray (dim_0: 1, dim_1: 1)>
array([[1]])
Coordinates:
  * dim_0    (dim_0) int64 1
  * dim_1    (dim_1) <U1 'a'
```

What do you think is the cleanest way to deal with this situation? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the clear question.

You can get the scalar with `.item()`:

```py
In [1]: In [1]: import xarray as xr
   ...:
   ...: In [2]: d = xr.DataArray([list('abc'), list('def')],
   ...:    ...:                  coords=[[1, 2], list('abc')])
   ...:

In [2]: d
Out[2]:
<xarray.DataArray (dim_0: 2, dim_1: 3)>
array([['a', 'b', 'c'],
       ['d', 'e', 'f']], dtype='<U1')
Coordinates:
  * dim_0    (dim_0) int64 1 2
  * dim_1    (dim_1) <U1 'a' 'b' 'c'

In [3]: x = d.sel(dict(dim_0=1, dim_1='a'))

In [4]: x
Out[4]:
<xarray.DataArray ()>
array('a', dtype='<U1')
Coordinates:
    dim_0    int64 1
    dim_1    <U1 'a'

In [5]: x.item()
Out[5]: 'a'
```

Xarray *always* returns an array from indexing methods, so that users can reason about types in their code. Otherwise, for example, if the underlying data changed, you might find yourself calling `.sum()` on a scalar.

Comment: Thanks @Maximilian for the answer... I found the .item() method for 0-dim arrays also in  https://www.numpy.org/neps/nep-0027-zero-rank-arrarys.html. It seems to be the best solution, although counterintuitive at first.